# Create a new directory in KDE Save As dialogue

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, kate

When using the KDE Save As dialogue, how does one create a new directory **using the keyboard only** (i.e. no need to grab the mouse)? The `Create New Directory` button is not readily accessible via <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and then getting back to the Filename control is another <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> mess. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and some other obvious guesses to no avail.

Additionally, I tried giving the filename as `newDirectory/someFile.txt` however that throws an error that the file is inaccessible (presumably due to the illegal `/` character in the name).

I'm currently using KDE 4.9 on Kubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>F10</kbd>. This shortcut is actual for Dolphin file manager and should work in `Save As` dialogue.

Comment: That works so well that it also `cd`'s into the new directory. Thank you!

Comment: Has this since changed? F10 does nothing for me in Dolphin or the dialog.

Comment: Still works for me in both. (Kubuntu 22.04, KDE 5.24.7, Dolphin & Kate 21.12.3)